# C HTTP Proxy, the browser shows "waiting for" indefinetely

Tags: c, sockets, http, proxy, blocking

I have a hard time implementing a proxy server in C. It works for a few first webpages but then I get blocked while waiting for a new request.

Design:

```
Firefox -> Proxy -> Webserver --.
Firefox <- Proxy <- Webserver <-'
```

So each request is a round-trip from the browser to the proxy and the server and then back. Until the response from the request comes back, nothing should happen. I use **no pipelining, threads** or anything like that but rather only `recv()` and `send()` in a linear serial manner (for simplicity and intuition). I also don't close any sockets as I want to have a **persistent connection**.

I expect to be able and fetch one whole webpage including subrequested resources like css, img, js, etc..

In my implementation I manage to fetch a few first requests for a webpage. Then it **hangs at step 1**.

Implementation:

```
puts("Waiting for user to connect..");
int sock_user = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
int sock_host = -1;
printf("User connected.\n");


// Accept requests
while(1){

   http_request req;
   http_response resp;


   // 1. Client ==> Proxy     Server
   http_parse_request(sock_user, &req);                         // uses recv()

   // 2. Client     Proxy ==> Server
   if (sock_host < 0)
      sock_host = proxy_connect_host(req.header->host);
   write(sock_host, req.header->raw_data, req.header->raw_size);

   // 3. Client     Proxy <== Server
   http_parse_response(sock_host, &resp);                      // uses recv()

   // 4. Client <== Proxy     Server
   write(sock_user, resp.header->raw_data,          resp.header->raw_size);
   write(sock_user, resp.body  ->first_block->data, resp.body  ->first_block->size);

}
```

Log:

```
     ---- ......................................... ----

     ---- after succesfully responded to 4 requests ----


Client ==> Proxy     Server
                                Received              389

Client     Proxy ==> Server
                                Sending..             389
                                Sent                  389

Client     Proxy <== Server
                                Got header            312
                                Got body              1437
                                Response total        1749

Client <== Proxy     Server
                                Sending header..      312
                                Sent                  312
                                Sending body..        1437
                                Sent                  1437

Client ==> Proxy     Server


                ---- Hangs/blocks here ----
```

Firebug:

[image]

Wireshark:
[image]

I have no intuition as to what the reason for that block is and I have spent a whole week trying to resolve this problem without a breakthrough.

Among things tried to resolve problem:

1. Sending some extra `CRLF` for each response body
2. Checked the return value from each `recv()` and `send()`. (*in the log above,
   the values getting printed are the return values from `recv` and
   `send`*)

I hope someone could give at least some direction as to how to troubleshoot this or my brain will soon explode :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful not to read too much data.  E.g. make sure that:

- header is read only up to the double CRLF; store extra data and sent them with the body
- sending of body starts not before the server has sent the complete header (does not apply to this GET case but is important for POST or CONNECT)
- there are received and sent only Content-Length bytes from the body

This applies to both the client -> proxy request and the server -> proxy response.

Your sample code stays in an endless loop (`while (1) ...`). How do you abort this? Do you honor the "Proxy-Connection" header?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did all over the parsing and now I am sure that the parsing is correct. Still the same problem though. My suspicion is that the client sends a bunch of requests that I never `recv()`

Comment: 'strace -s 9999 -erecv,send -p <your-proxy-pid>' might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. Nice suggestion but that just confirmed that the actual data received and sent is the same and in the correct format.